# Download Phonegap or Cordova 3.1

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I heard phonegap/cordova version 3.1 was released but I have yet to see how to download it. I have used the CLI command to check for 3.1 and all I see is 3.0.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Answer (score 4):

Cordova 3.1 has just been released today.

You can get the latest version via npm: https://npmjs.org/package/cordova

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/), the latest release is 3.0, not 3.1.

The Archive found [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/) does not contain 3.1, and the Download link only shows 3.0.0 which is the latest.

Comment: In addition the cordova project shows that it has not yet been released (no release date):
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/

Comment: But the phonegap.com website says:Apache Cordova has released 3.1.0. As PhoneGap is based upon the open source project Apache Cordova, the PhoneGap team is hard at work upgrading the PhoneGap CLI to 3.1.0 and will have a release shortly. In the meantime, you can innstall Cordova 3.1 with the following command:

$ sudo npm install -g cordova
            
Read more on how to use the Cordova CLI.

Learn more about Apache Cordova’s relationship to PhoneGap by reading Brian LeRoux’s blog post PhoneGap, Cordova, and what’s in a name?

Answer (score 2):

To check your current version:

```
phonegap --version
```

or

```
phonegap -v
```

To see the latest version:

```
npm info phonegap version
```

Run this command to update:

```
npm update -g phonegap
```

Also, one way to get notified when it updates you can use npm-onupdate. To install npm-onupdate

```
npm install -g npm-onupdate
npm-onupdate add phonegap
```

To list out the packages you're signed up to get alerts for:

```
npm-onupdate ls
```

Answer (score 1):

It' released, see docs here [cordova.apache.org](http://cordova.apache.org/blog/releases/2013/10/02/cordova-31.html)